# Google sheetsFormat numbers as billions / millions / thousands, smartly

Tags: google-sheets

I have this template format for the numbers:

```
[>=999950]0.0,,"M";[<=-999950]0.0,,"M";0.0,"K"
```

[image: Example]

But how can I do to make Zeros show as " - " ?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest that you're looking for something like this

```
[>=999950]0.0,,"M";[<=-999950]0.0,,"M";#,,"-"
```

[image]

### Updated

As @Benoît Wéry said it's not possible. But I think you can.

I'm using a simple script for build a good view

[image]

```
function formatToMKZeros(range) {
  var values = range.getValues();
  return range.setNumberFormats(
    range.getNumberFormats().map(function(row, r) {
      return row.map(function(format, c) {
        return isNumeric(values[r][c])
          ? values[r][c] !== 0 && Math.abs(values[r][c]) < 999950
            ? '[<999950]0.0,"K";[>-999950]0.0,"K"'
            : '[>=999950]0.0,,"M";[<=-999950]0.0,,"M";#,,"-"'
          : format;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

- [The full
  code](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet-multiple_formats/multiple_formats.js)
- The great article about formats [Handling Negative Numbers in a
  Complex Custom
  Format](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T010227_Handling_Negative_Numbers_in_a_Complex_Custom_Format.html)
- Also simple samples [The Only Spreadsheet Custom Number Format You’ll
  Ever
  Need](https://medium.com/@brookinc/the-only-spreadsheet-custom-number-format-you-ll-ever-need-7cc356a7ca3e)

Comment: Yes, but I still need to show the K values, for positive and negative values

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can:

> Conditions can only be applied to the first two sub-formats and if a number matches more than one, it will use the first one it matches. If there is a third format, it will be used for "everything else", otherwise if a number doesn’t match either format, it will be rendered as all "#"s filling up the cell width. The fourth format is always used for text, if it exists.

Source: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#meta_instructions